# Encrypting string to 15 characters

Tags: c#, encryption

I am doing this serial key thing where the format is xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx (15 characters).
I can currently encrypt my string but the problems are:

1. 6 Characters become 20+ Characters.
2. Has some underieable characters such as: +, /, =

So what would be the best way to encrypt a string to certain number of characters?
In my case: 6 characters encrypted to 15 characters.

I am currently using something like this:

```
    public string EncryptString(string clearText, string Password)
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, ByteGetter(UsageMode, "Password")); 
        byte[] encryptedData = EncryptByte(clearBytes, pdb.GetBytes(32), pdb.GetBytes(16));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }


    public static byte[] EncryptByte(byte[] clearData, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
        alg.Key = Key;
        alg.IV = IV;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
        cs.Close();
        byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
        return encryptedData;
    }
```

Comment: Pedantic aside: it's hashing more than encryption if you can't reverse the algorithm. So I guess the recommendation would be to use a hash function (you're using PBKDF2 which can be considered one), skip the encryption step which is pointless after you hash your input data, encode it using Base32 instead of Base64, and just discard the extra characters you don't need.

Comment: I would like to reverse the algorithm. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you want to reverse the algorithm, you can't discard data or limit the output to a fixed size.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware I cant discard data. That's why I was trying to make the whole output 15 characters. So I'm not discarding any data and able to use that that data to reverse the algorithm.

Comment: So basically, I just want 6 characters encrypted to 15 characters(Without symbols like +, /, =). Which can also be reversed.

Comment: You can either want: **1.** The input to be fixed at 6 characters; **2.** The output to be fixed at 15 characters; **3.** To use an existing encryption function and not invent one for your specific use case. *Pick two.* (At most. It's still possible the encryption algorithm blows up even very small inputs.) If Rijndael encrypts 6 characters to 20 base64 characters, you simply cannot make the output smaller without discarding data. And certainly not by reencoding it into a character set that's smaller than base64.

Comment: I pick 1 and 2. If it's not possible I pick 3. I already got 3 working but was hoping 1 and 2 would work.

Comment: Well, if you picked 1 and 2 then the next step is obvious. Implement your own reversible encryption algorithm where the output for any 6 characters is 15 alphanumerical characters. If you pick 3, the next step is also obvious - allow the serial code to be as big as necessary to contain the ciphertext encrypted in base-32 (the least wasteful encoding that's only alphanumerics), or hex digits (guaranteed to not require padding).

Comment: And, if I understand AES correctly, there isn't any sensible way to constrain the output size. It's a block cipher that works on 128-bit chunks of data.

Comment: I guess I'll try the later. I'll allow my serial code to get bigger. So your saying if I encode to another method like base-32, it'll only contain alphanumerical characters?

Comment: It depends on the alphabet. Wiki tells me that the one from [RFC4648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) uses `=` for padding, but is otherwise uppercase characters and digits. You can handle that in a few ways. You can replace the padding character with one of the unused characters. (`0`, `1`, `8`, `9`). Or you could automatically add the required number of padding characters before decoding / remove them after encoding. (I.e. in base32 the string being decoded needs to have a length that's a multiple of 8.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you like to make a post about it? So I may be able to select it as best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synthetising the comment thread from the question:

If you want the serial code to be (reversibly) encrypted data, you can't really constrain its size very well. You're stuck with whatever the encryption algorithm gives you, and they usually operate on fixed-size blocks.

The obvious choices for encoding the encrypted data into a bunch of ASCII characters are:

- **base64** - widely supported, but can't be implemented using only alphanumerics, and is case-sensitive
- **base32** - somewhat obscure - you'll have to write / find an implementation. The [RFC-specified](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) standard requires padding with `=`s. (Just as it does for *base64*.) More compact than *base16*, and only needs case-insensitive alphanumerics for the data, which is an advantage if you expect people to type the code by hand.
- **base16** - also very well supported, never requires padding, but is far less compact than the other two.

You can work around the padding issue knowing that the length of the encoded string has to be a multiple of 8 for *base32*, and a multiple of *4* for base64. (I'm not 100% sure about this, but it makes sense, since you want the encoded string to represent a multiple of 8 bits.) Knowing this you can add padding characters to make a decoder stop complaining about an invalid input length. (`Convert.FromBase64String()` does complain.)

If you want to constrain the output size given an input size in some specific way, and aren't willing to discard data (i.e. hash instead of encrypting), you'll have to roll your own encryption algorithm. This seems mostly counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It is a property of Base64-encoding to contain non-alpha characters. So you will need to chose another encoding, you might want to start use 5 bit parcels and encode to A-Z, 2-9 but leave out O,I. This should give you the character set you wish.

Second: Assuming you do chose 5 bit packets, you need 5*15=75 bits. Most hashes will create 128 bits ore more, so you need to downsample. A possible way to approach this is to simply ignore bits.

Answer (score 0):

With your requirements you need to:

- Encrypt with DES
- Encode with Base 32 (base 16 will give you 16 bytes instead of 15)
- Pad however you like